# Busca com múltiplos filtros

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tenho essa estrutura, como eu posso fazer para que eu consiga ter um select que me dê opções de preços mais altos ou mais baixos? esse script ele apenas lista os dados por categoria, eu não sei como implementar para que tenha a possibilidade de ordenar os preços, além disso parece só funcionar com checkbox:

Database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mobile_phones` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `price` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `samsung` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `iphone` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `htc` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `lg` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 `nokia` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Tabela:

```
INSERT INTO `mobile_phones` (`id`, `name`, `price`, `samsung`, `iphone`,
`htc`, `lg`, `nokia`) VALUES
(1, 'Samsung Galaxy S 1', 180, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(2, 'Samsung Galaxy S 2', 220, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(3, 'Samsung Galaxy S 3', 300, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(4, 'Samsung Galaxy S 4', 450, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(5, 'Samsung Galaxy S 4 mini', 400, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0),
(6, 'Iphone 3GS', 150, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(7, 'Iphone 4', 200, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(8, 'Iphone 4S', 250, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(9, 'Iphone 5', 300, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(10, 'Iphone 5S', 350, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0),
(11, 'Htc Desire', 150, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
(12, 'Htc Desire200', 200, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
(13, 'Htc Desire500', 250, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
(14, 'Htc One', 400, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
(15, 'Htc One mini', 250, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0),
(16, 'Lg Optimus L3', 150, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(17, 'Lg Optimus L5', 250, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(18, 'Lg Optimus L7', 350, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(19, 'Lg Optimus L9', 400, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(20, 'Lg Optimus G2', 450, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0),
(21, 'Nokia 100', 50, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(22, 'Nokia E72', 100, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(23, 'Nokia E6', 150, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(24, 'Nokia Lumia 520', 200, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1),
(25, 'Nokia Lumia 620', 250, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
```

submit.php:

```
<?php 
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=sitepoint', 'root', '');
  $select = 'SELECT *';
  $from = ' FROM mobile_phones';
  $where = ' WHERE ';
  $opts = $_POST['filterOpts'];

  if (empty($opts)){
    // 0 checkboxes checked
    $where .= 'TRUE';
  } else {
    if(count($opts) == 1){
      // 1 checkbox checked
      $where .= $opts[0] . ' = 1';
    } else {
      // 2+ checkboxes checked
      $where .= implode(' = 1 OR ', $opts) . ' = 1';
    }
  }

  $sql = $select . $from . $where;
  $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $statement->execute();
  $results = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json = json_encode($results);
  echo($json);
?>
```

index.php:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>AJAX filter demo</title>
    <style>
      body {
        padding: 10px;
      }

      h1 {
          margin: 0 0 0.5em 0;
          color: #343434;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-family: 'Ultra', sans-serif;   
          font-size: 36px;
          line-height: 42px;
          text-transform: uppercase;
          text-shadow: 0 2px white, 0 3px #777;
      }

      h2 {
          margin: 1em 0 0.3em 0;
          color: #343434;
          font-weight: normal;
          font-size: 30px;
          line-height: 40px;
          font-family: 'Orienta', sans-serif;
      }

      #phones {
        font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif;
        font-size: 12px;
        background: #fff;
        margin: 15px 25px 0 0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        text-align: center;
        float: left;
        width: 700px;
      }

      #phones th {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-weight: normal;
        color: #039;
        padding: 10px 8px;
        border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;
      }

      #phones td {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
        color: #669;
        padding: 8px 10px;
      }

      #phones tbody tr:hover td {
        color: #009;
      }

      #filter {
        float:left;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body> 
    <h1>Phones database</h1>

    <table id="phones">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Price</th>
          <th>Samsung</th>
          <th>iPhone</th>
          <th>HTC</th>
          <th>LG</th>
          <th>Nokia</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="filter">
      <h2>Filter options</h2>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="samsung">
        <label for="samsung">Samsung</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="iphone">
        <label for="iphone">iPhone</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="htc">
        <label for="htc">HTC</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="lg">
        <label for="lg">LG</label>
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="nokia">
        <label for="nokia">Nokia</label>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script>
      function makeTable(data){
       var tbl_body = "";
          $.each(data, function() {
            var tbl_row = "";
            $.each(this, function(k , v) {
              tbl_row += "<td>"+v+"</td>";
            })
            tbl_body += "<tr>"+tbl_row+"</tr>";                 
          })

        return tbl_body;
      }

      function getPhoneFilterOptions(){
        var opts = [];
        $checkboxes.each(function(){
          if(this.checked){
            opts.push(this.id);
          }
        });

        return opts;
      }

      function updatePhones(opts){
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "submit.php",
          dataType : 'json',
          cache: false,
          data: {filterOpts: opts},
          success: function(records){
            $('#phones tbody').html(makeTable(records));
          }
        });
      }

      var $checkboxes = $("input:checkbox");
      $checkboxes.on("change", function(){
        var opts = getPhoneFilterOptions();
        updatePhones(opts);
      });

      updatePhones();
    </script> 
  </body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Olá Otavio Fagundes, gostaria de saber se minha resposta tem lhe ajudado.

Answer (score 0):

**Como eu posso fazer para que eu consiga ter um select que me dê opções de preços mais altos ou mais baixos?**

A resposta para a sua pergunta seria utilizando a cláusula *ORDER BY ASC* ou *DESC*.
Exemplo:

`SELECT * FROM mobile_phones WHERE price ORDER BY ASC/DESC`

Dica: ASC Classifica os resultados em ordem crescente, caso você não adicione um valor(asc ou desc) por padrão o asc será utilizado.

DESC Classifica o resultado definido em ordem decrescente.

Durante a montagem de seu código SQL no arquivo *submit.php*, a implementação adicional que você deveria fazer seria de adaptar o código PHP para fazer essa consulta quando fosse necessário.